# Should I use inherited tests?

Tags: unit-testing, inheritance

I am reviewing some code where the developer has some classes ClassA and ClassB. They both inherit from ParentClass so both must implement a number of abstract methods (e.g. `return5Values(2)`)

In ClassA the values are all double the previous value: `[2,4,8,16,32]`
In ClassB the values are all +1 the previous value `[2,3,4,5,6]`

There are also other constraints such as raising an error if the parameter is negative etc.

Other tests like getting the 3rd value only, also exist etc.

(Obviously these are just fake examples to get my point across)

Now, instead of writing a lot of similar tests for both ClassA and ClassB, what the developer has done is created `ParentClassChildTests` which contains a some code something like this:

```
public void testVariablesAreCorrect() {
  returnedValues = clazz.return5Values(2)
  # Does a bunch of other things as well
  # ...
  assertEqual(expectedValues, returnedValues)
}
```

`ClassATests` now inherits from `ParentClassChildTest` and must define `expectedValues` as a class variable.

The `expectedValues` are used within a few different tests as well, so they aren't being defined just for this single test.

Now when `ClassATests` and `ClassBTests` are run, it also runs all the tests inside `ParentClassChildTests`.

My question is: Is this a good method to avoid a lot of duplicate tests and ensure everything works as expected in child classes? Are there any major issues this can lead to? Or a better way of handling this?

Whilst this is all Java code, my question isn't about any particular testing framework or language but the idea in general of inheriting from a parent class which also has tests in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation that it is possible and sensible to re-use tests for different implementations of an interface / base class is not very common.  The following aspects limit the applicability:

- Derived classes have different dependencies, which may require different mocks to be created and to be set up.  In such a case, the test methods can not be identical.  Even if `classA` and `classB` currently do not have dependencies or the same dependencies with (coincidentially) the same setup, this can change over time or the next class `classC` will have different dependencies.
- Each derived class will implement different algorithms.  In your case, `return5Values` performs different algorithms in `ClassA` and `ClassB`.  Due to the different algorithms, the behaviour of the SUT for the same set up and the same inputs may be different: For example, each algorithm will run into overflows at different points.  Even the call `return5Values(2)` that allows to use a derived test for `classA` and `classB` today, could with a potential future `classC` lead to an overflow scenario with possible exceptions thrown.
- The different algorithms implemented in the derived classes will have different potential bugs and different corner cases.  That is, the necessary set up and inputs for the SUT will have to be different to stimulate the respective boundaries.  For some implementations, testing the call `return5Values(2)` may simply not bring any benefit while test for other parameters than `2` are necessary.
- If you share test methods between the classes and only provide the parameters, it is not the test method which is associated with the tests' intent - each parameter set has its own intent.  The intent/scenario, however, should ideally be part of the output of each individual test.

Given all these problems, inheritance of test methods does not seem to be the best approach for re-use here.  Instead, it may be more beneficial to have have some common helper functions that can be used by the different derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Having class hierarchies in tests creates dependencies between them. A `UnitTest` serves the purpose of testing a `Unit` in isolation where `Unit` refers to a certain class. I'd argue that it is ok to have helpers and utils to avoid duplicating very basic functionality.

As much as possible unit tests should allow for quick and independent changes of a certain `Unit`. Having a commonly enforced structure for all tests increases the amount of work to be done if the implementation of unrelated parts of the application changes.

When it comes to integration testing there will be shared functionality for setting up the infrastructure. So the answer is a very clear *it depends*. Generally it is favorable to reduce dependencies between tests as much as possible and having a base test that determines the inner workings of a derived test is detrimental to that goal.